# create and download zip archive in php

Tags: php, download, zip, php-ziparchive

I have created a zip file and download that. But my problem is that I just want to download specific files not the complete files of the root folder.

My code is

```
$zipname = 'documents.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($allDocuments as $document) {
  $filetopath = public_path().$document;
  $filename = explode('/',$document);
  $name = end($filename);
  $zip->addFile($filetopath,$name);
 }
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

I just want to make a zip file which has only files named, not any folder and have specific files not all files of the root folder. But I am getting all folder and all files by this.

In $alldocumnets variable I am getting a limited record, not all records.
But when creating zip it gets all files.

I don't understand where I am getting wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The question about the directories is clear: just exclude everything that is_dir() == true

```
<?php
$allDocuments = array("a.py","b.py");

$zipname = 'documents.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach($allDocuments as $document) {
  $filetopath = getcwd().'\\'.$document;
  if(!is_dir($filetopath)) {
    $filename = explode('/',$document);
    $name = end($filename);
    $zip->addFile($filetopath,$name);
  }
 }
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

Unfortunately, the second part is not clear. As long as you do not tell us which files you intent do exclude or what's the exact problem this is unsalvageable.

Comment: I have fixed this by setting zipname dynamically.
Actually I have date range and depending on that range I get documents from database and create a zip file and download.
If I set log range then I have many files in zip which is fine. But after that If I set a small date range then I should get less files but Still I was getting all previous files. This is because of same zipname.

Comment: When I set zipname dynamic then It's working fine.
But this is not best solution I need best solution of this issue.
I also used
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean. I this answer is not helpful I kindly remove it. Otherwise, upvote and accept, please.